# Navigation bar button visibility issue in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am having issue with the navigation bar buttons. It looks good(visible) when present the view controller. When I present a another view controller on it it disappears the previous view controller bar button item (But they work when taps but not visible).

I am presenting the new view controller like this

```
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: serverPhotosCategoryVC)
            navVC.modalTransitionStyle = presentationStyle
            appDelegateObj.navigationController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please let me know what could be the issue.
I have tried many types of codes for that. But they can't help it.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes buttons are visible and sometimes not.

Comment: why don't you use a push instead of present?

Comment: @koropok, because pushing a view controller adds a new step further and I don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

If you present from viewController, should present from viewController instead of using navigationController

```
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: serverPhotosCategoryVC)
navVC.modalTransitionStyle = presentationStyle
self.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: And now showing instead of presenting the view controller
Button of bar button is hiding. When goes from one screen to another